# SEO friendly URL not working using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to implement a SEO friendly URL using .htaccess by using the RewriteRule below

```
RewriteRule ^n/article/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ article.php?title=$1
```

The actaul URL looks like this

```
http://localhost/n/article.php?title=this-is-the-first-news-article
```

but I want it to look like this :

```
http://localohst/n/article/this-is-the-first-news-article
```

When I applied the RewiteRule above it does not change to the desired URL

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled ?

Comment: I’d remove `title` from the URL as Farkie says. It serves no purpose being there.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. You are missing the n. Not sure why you need the word title though.

```
RewriteRule ^n/article/title/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ article.php?title=$1
```

Comment: I removed `title` from the URL and used this `RewriteRule ^n/article/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ article.php?title=$1` But still not working.

Comment: This is backward from what they're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the query string first. You can't do that with a RewriteRule because they ignore the query string. Here we're using `[R]` to redirect. If this is working for you and there is the potential that the old URLs are being stored somewhere as links, then you may want to specify `[R=301]`. Be sure to remove all old-style links from your site though (that contain the previous link format we're rewriting), that way you're not penalized for not updating your links.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^n/article.php n/article/%1? [R,L]
```

If your site needs the formatting to function from the original, you might also need this after the first rule. This rule quietly redirects the URL back to the original without showing it to the end user:

```
RewriteRule ^n/article/(.*) n/article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is still not working. I still get the normal url

Answer (score 0):

it will be RewriteRule ^n/article/title/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ article.php?title=$1

Comment: This is the reverse of what they're asking for.